# Display json in ul using java script

Tags: javascript

I have one simple json

```
{
 "subjectObj": [{
  "id": "1",
  "option": "java"
 }, {
  "id": "2",
  "option": "c++"
 },{
  "id": "3",
  "option": "c"
}]
}
```

I just want to display this json as `ul`.I did this using jquery but I want to do it java script.

```
function OnSuccess(data) {
    $.each(data, function() {
        $("#ulCategory").append("<li>" + this.option + "</li>");
    });
}

<body>
<div id="ulCategory"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: How does your vanilla javascript  code look like? Where do you have a problem to converter it to vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DOM way ("pure javascript way") for this would be (assuming ES5!):

```js
function OnSuccess(data) { // assuming data is the array from subjectObj, otherwhise use data  data.subjectObj for the loop

      var ulCategory = document.getElementById('ulCategory');

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { // replacing the $.each loop

            var liEl = document.createElement('li'); // create the element
            liEl.innerText = data[i].option; // add the text (if it would be HTML add liEl.innerHTML but be sure you know and parse what you insert, othrewhise you will open for XSS injections

            ulCategory.append(liEl); // append it to your ul
            
      }
    }
```

**EDIT**: moved the DOM lookup to a variable for performance reasons from suggestions of the comments.

Comment: No need to query the DOM multiple times to fetch the node with id `ulCategory`. For performance reasons, do it once and store it in a variable.

Comment: how can I add `<a>` tag for each json data>?

Comment: @NicoVanBelle yup - you're right... move document.getElementById('ulCategory') to the top...

@krish; do you want to add the a as a child of the li or as a replacement? replacement would be: document.createElement('a');

Comment: no no I want to add as a child.. I tried this `listElement.setAttribute('href',"www.google.com")` but its not working.

Comment: How can I give different `links` for each subject

Comment: You could create additional elements and append them to the liElement (because the liElement is not a link element). after "liEl.innerText = data[i].option;" add like: var aElement = document.createElement('a'); /* do anything with aElement here, like setting attributes or links */ liElement.append(aElement);

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of jQuery and do it in plain javascript you can try the following code. It creates an `ul` element and then populated the `li` items in a loop.

```
function OnSuccess(data) {
    var categoryList = document.getElementById('ulCategory');
    var ulElement = document.createElement("ul");
    categoryList.appendChild(ulElement);

    data.subjectObj.forEach(item => {
        var liElement = document.createElement("li");
        liElement.textContent = item.option;
        ulElement.appendChild(liElement);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your function as below, You need to loop through the array that is `data.subjectObj`

```
function OnSuccess(data) {
    $.each(data.subjectObj, function(index) {
    debugger;
        $("#ulCategory").append("<li>" + this.option + "</li>");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function format(data) {
        if (typeof(data) == 'object') {
            document.write('<ul>');
            for (var i in data) {
                document.write('<li>' + i);
                format(data[i]);
            }
            document.write('</ul>');
        } else {
            document.write(' => ' + data);
        }
    }


    json = {
        "subjectObj": [{
            "id": "1",
            "option": "java"
        }, {
            "id": "2",
            "option": "c++"
        }, {
            "id": "3",
            "option": "c"
        }]
    }
    format(json)
</script>
```